# how to increment population/neverending loop

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner who has some questions relating to my homework for school.

With my current code I'm stuck in a neverending loop which I'm assuming is because my condition is never actually met (Pop A being greater than Pop B) and I'm unsure how to move on. I'm also not sure how to properly increment/calculate the years needed for Town A to surpass Town B but this is what I've got so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int townA;
    int townB;
    double growthA;
    double growthB;
    double finalA;
    double finalB;
    int years = 0;

    cout << "Enter the population of town A: ";
    cin >> townA;
    cout << "Enter the growth rate of town A: ";
    cin >> growthA;
    cout << "Enter the population of town B: ";
    cin >> townB;
    cout << "Enter the growth rate of town B: ";
    cin >> growthB;

    while ((townA <= 0) && (growthA <=0) && (townB > townA) && (growthB < growthA) && (growthB > 0))
    {
        cout << "Error: Values must be positive, please try again." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the population of town A: ";
        cin >> townA;
        cout << "Enter the growth rate of town A: ";
        cin >> growthA;
        cout << "Enter the population of town B: ";
        cin >> townB;
        cout << "Enter the growth rate of town B: ";
        cin >> growthB;
        cout << endl;
    }

    years = 0;
    while (townA <= townB)
    {
        finalA = ((growthA / 100) * (townA)) + townA;
        finalB = ((growthB / 100) * (townB)) + townB;
        cout << "It took Town A " << years << " years to exceed the population of Town B." << endl;
        cout << "Town A " << finalA << endl;
        cout << "Town B " << finalB << endl;
    }

        cout << "\n\n" << endl;    // Teacher required us to output it to the screen incase anyone is wondering why I have this block
        cout << setw(3) << "Town A" << setw(15) << "Town B" << endl;
        cout << setw(3) << growthA << "%" << setw(10) << growthB << "%" << endl;
        cout << setw(3) << townA << setw(7) << townB << endl;
        cout << "Year" << endl;
        cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the values of `townA` and `townB` in the loop. Hence, you never get out of the loop.

Also, you need to increment `years` in the loop. Use:

```
while (townA <= townB)
{
   finalA = ((growthA / 100) * (townA)) + townA;
   finalB = ((growthB / 100) * (townB)) + townB;
   cout << "Town A " << finalA << endl;
   cout << "Town B " << finalB << endl;

   // Update the values of the key variables.
   ++years;
   townA = finalA;
   townB = finalB;
}

// This needs to be moved from the loop.
cout << "It took Town A " << years << " years to exceed the population of Town B." << endl;
```